# NQunit.NUnit getting started guide

Tags: nunit, qunit

does anybody know of a good tutorial for getting started with NQUnit.NUnit.

I've installed it to my test project via nuget and am unsure what the blank.js and async.js files are all about, should I rename these to match my files under test or do I just add my asyncronous and syncronous tests to the respective files.

ta!

Answer (score 3):

Find the answer in the following link:
[NQUnit: JavaScript testing within .NET / CI](http://robdmoore.id.au/blog/2011/03/13/nqunit-javascript-testing-within-net-ci/)